Script para actualizar una formula en base a una variable
soy nuevo en apps script de google, les planteo lo que pretendo lograr:
Tengo una una formula importrange que copia toda la información de una hoja de otro archivo de google sheets. Cada día se añade una nueva hoja al archivo origen y cada hoja tiene como nombre la fecha en formato dd/mm/yy.
Necesito crear un script capaz de:
1.- Duplicar una de mis hojas ya trabajadas
2.- Cambiar el nombre de la nueva hoja por la fecha del día de hoy
3.- Modificar la formula importrange de la hoja recien creada, para que el nombre de hoja a que hace referencia la formula sea igual a la fecha actual.
Hasta ahora he podido crear el siguiente código:
function Duplicarhoja5() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); fecha = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT-06:00","dd/MM/yy");
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('04/05/24'), true);
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName(fecha);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula("=IMPORTRANGE('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19lcZAc9vO_74_yB9Pa-C_3BgMHADVRXVyeoCFqUoLoL/edit#gid=302075400';'"+fecha+'!A:Q")');
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Conteo'), true);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(fecha), true);
  spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet(5);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Conteo'), true);
};

Este código cumple los primeros dos puntos, sin embargo no logro introducir la formula IMPORTRANGE de forma correcta, puesto que no se escriben las comillas " " y por lo tanto no reconoce los argumentos de la formula como validos; si dentro del script coloco las comillas en el lugar que corresponde
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula("=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19lcZAc9vO_74_yB9Pa-C_3BgMHADVRXVyeoCFqUoLoL/edit#gid=302075400";"+fecha+!A:Q")");

El script me arroja error de sintaxis y no permite guardarlo.
Espero haberme explicado y me puedan ayudar.

Respuesta para quien le sea útil:
Al fin pude resolver mi problema, se trataba de un error de sintaxis.
En la línea mencionada solo cambié la manera en que se llama a la variable fecha, quedando de la siguiente manera:
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormulaR1C1('=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19lcZAc9vO_74_yB9Pa-C_3BgMHADVRXVyeoCFqUoLoL/edit#gid=302070000";"'+fecha+'!A:Q")');

Con esta corrección el script funciona correctamente.
